# Datatables export buttons not showing

Tags: jquery, datatable, export

I have a table that is made in the $( document ).ready function. I am also using the jQuery DataTables plugin. For some reason, when the page loads, the datatable loads but the export buttons don't.

```
function loadAct() {
            var url = 'http://10.26.192.70/apns/index.php/Busqueda_c/listarAsignaciones';
            $.post(url, {
            }, function (data) {
                var arrayAsignaciones = JSON.parse(data);
                // INGRESA INFORMACION DENTRO DE CADA TABLA DESPUES DE HABER AGREGADO UNA ASIGNACION
                for (i = 1; i < arrayAsignaciones.length; i++) {
                    var str2 = arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_TipoActa;
                    var id2 = str2.replace(/ /gi, '-');
                    var idtable2 = 'table-' + id2;
                    var idtbody2 = 'tbody-' + id2;
                    var table = document.getElementById(idtable2);
                    var tbody = document.getElementById(idtbody2);
                    // Aca comienza la creacion del <tbody> 
                    $(table).find(tbody).append(
                            "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_Grado + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_Nombre + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_Rut + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_Codigo + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_Dotacion + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_FechaInicio + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_FechaTermino + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" +
                            "<a href='#' onclick='eliminarAsignacion(" + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_Rut + ", " + arrayAsignaciones[i].Act_Id + ");return false;'>" +
                            "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' style='margin-left:25px; font-size:15px; color:red;'>" +
                            "</span>" +
                            "</a>" +
                            "</td>" +
                            "</tr>"
                            );

                    // Aca termina la creacion del <tbody> 
                }

                $('.tableBody').DataTable({
                    dom: 'Blfltip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copyHtml5',
                        'excel',
                        'csvHtml5',
                        'pdfHtml5'
                    ],
                        "sDom": 'rt',
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false,
                        ordering: false
                });
            });
        }
```

But it is not showing any export button and I can't resolve it.

I also included the following Javascript and CSS from the dateTable download builder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.6/jq-2.2.3/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.12/af-2.1.2/b-1.2.2/b-colvis-1.2.2/b-flash-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/b-print-1.2.2/cr-1.3.2/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.1.3/r-2.1.0/rr-1.1.2/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.6/jq-2.2.3/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.18/dt-1.10.12/af-2.1.2/b-1.2.2/b-colvis-1.2.2/b-flash-1.2.2/b-html5-1.2.2/b-print-1.2.2/cr-1.3.2/fc-3.2.2/fh-3.1.2/kt-2.1.3/r-2.1.0/rr-1.1.2/sc-1.4.2/se-1.2.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the HTML where I use the dataTabe:

```
<div class="panel panel-success" id="" style="width:1400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto ">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><h3 class="panel-title">PILOTOS (17%)</h3></td>
                    <td><div></div></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
            
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="PILOTOS-(17%)">
        <div id="table-PILOTOS-(17%)_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
            <table class="display tableBody dataTable no-footer" id="table-PILOTOS-(17%)" role="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">GRADO</th>
                        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">NOMBRE</th>
                        <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">RUN</th>
```

CODIGO
                            DOTACION
                            FECHA INICIO
                            FECHA TERMINO
                            ELIMINAR
                    
                    
                        C.P.R.  GDO. 12
                            asdf asdf asdf asdf
                            asdfasdf
                            asdfasdf
                            SEC. INFORMATICA (P.7).
                            03/08/2016
                            04/08/2016

Comment: I recommend creating a working fidlde (https://jsfiddle.net/)  and posting the link here. We would be more able to assist you.

Comment: With the given information (I am unable to access your URL - http://10.26.192.70... ) I cannot see what is wrong. Are you able to post the html here so we can assist?

Comment: i edit the question with the html code where i use the datatable plugins thanks

Comment: any chance you could paste the rendered HTML instead of the PHP page? https://jsfiddle.net/happymacarts/gvr2oyyz/ fork or modify that fiddle

Comment: i hope this help... i try to generate the html code of one of the tables

Answer (score 4):

Please remove **"sDom": 'rt'** it may be causing the issue.

From HTML and JS you have provided I can see you have used DOM onject as below

```
   dom: 'Blfltip'
```

Please change it to

```
dom: 'Bfrtip'
```

This might be the issue.

Also initiate the DataTable on whole table part not on table body.
Like :

```
 $('.dataTable').DataTable({
```

Check if you have included all the required CSS and JS files as well. 
Otherwise your code looks fine.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/rbunuv9b/2/

Reference : https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: Also make sure to instantiate the table not the table body $('.dataTable').DataTable();

Comment: I change the DOM option to 'Bfrtip' an check de Javascript library files one by one... and nothing...
Also i instantiate the table tableBody is just the name of the entire table

still nothing thanks guys

Comment: I have edited my answer please remove "sDom": 'rt' from your code its causing the issue.

Comment: the 'Bfrtip' only changes which items will diplay snd the order they display B - Buttons
l - Length etc read more https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

for example you could have 'Blfltip' as you had initially it would just display the length 2x

but there must be something else going on I STRONGLY recommend  using a fiddle to help isolate potential issues and make sure you have included all the necessary embedded files start with one of our fiddles and modify them https://jsfiddle.net/happymacarts/kx82svuo/1/

Comment: i replicate my code here https://jsfiddle.net/rbunuv9b/7/ and it works but in my localhost dont.... i dont understand wtf is happening rolf

Comment: Guys i found the stupid problem in my code....

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("../../js/jquery.dataTables.js"); ?>

this line was hidden after the js script functions in the head i remove it and voila!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this example  [Here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) .

It works for me.

1. Add all js as this order.

   ```
   https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
   https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
   https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js
   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js
   https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js
   ```
2. Add css.

   ```
   https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css      

   https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
   ```
3. Initailize Datatable as example.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
         'copyHtml5',
         'excelHtml5',
         'csvHtml5',
         'pdfHtml5'
       ]
     } );
   } );
   ```